# Is every point estimate for big data sets a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

Please, can someone help me out. I just started reading a stats textbook on inference and point estimates. According to the central limit theorem, we can approximate every sample to be a normal distribution as long as np and n(1-p) are > 10. Now my confusion is: does it mean that when I sample a data set like 10% of a data set that has 20,000 rows, I should be expecting to use a normal distribution to get relevant statistics? Is this true for every case provided np and n(1-p) are > 10 even if the random variable is discrete? that is my confusion. I am asking this because I want to get into data analysis and I believe this is what I should be expecting on the field.

Comment: The theorem holds for the *average* (or *sum*) of $n$ samples, not for the individual samples, which can follow any distribution. In the case a a binomial distribution, we have a sum of Bernouilli variables.

Comment: OK. that means if I am taking only an individual sample, I need to find out its distribution and then calculate its mean, std dev or expected values based on just that. Right?

Comment: Er, I don't know. It depends what you want to do with the data.